# How to copy existing dashboard to the new Project in Appdynamics

Tags: dashboard, appdynamics

How to copy an existing dashboard to the new project in appdynamics.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the dashboard and you will get the json version of your dashboard.(The export button is located top of the your dashboard page)

This json file can be easily editable with any editor and you can replace the Application and/or other properties which contain on of your dashboards.

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Import+and+Export+Custom+Dashboards+and+Templates+Using+the+UI